# FreeBSD ipfw tablearg

Tags: freebsd, ipfw

I'm configuring the FreeBSD firewall and have such situation:

```
51000 pipe tablearg ip from not table(17) to table(20) out xmit ng*
51010 pipe tablearg ip from table(21) to not table(17) in recv ng*
51020 pipe tablearg ip from any to table(18) out xmit ng*
51030 pipe tablearg ip from table(19) to any in recv ng*
```

Tables `18`,`19`,`20`,`21` have client IP addresses and pipe numbers;
table 17 - list of networks.

Rules `51020` and `51030` work fine but what is going on at `51000` and `51010`?
How to determine firewall to take pipe number from tables `20` and `21` - not from `17`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting ipfw tableargs from tables when two tables are used:
If 'not' statement is not used before destination table (second in row) pipe tablearg will be taken from it. In other case will be used other table. Totally we have: in `rule 51000` is used `table 20` and in `rule 51010` - `table 21`.